# Error opening documents with WPS from ntfs disk

Tags: permissions, 19.04, ntfs, wps-office

When trying to open documents (spreadsheets, presentations or text files) with WPS office the following error occurs:

> Errors occur when WPS Spreadsheets opening this file. Please try one
>   of the following. •Make sure you are permitted to access this file or
>   drive. •Make sure there is enough memory and disk space.   •Make sure
>   this file is recognizable format. (/media/user/Dates/WORK/02 - GOE
>   Feb2020.xls)

This error does not occur with LibreOffice. as the error indicates it must be a problem with the permissions but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: If you installed the `snap` version of WPS Office it will not read outside of your home folder to access files since it is a Sandboxed app.

Comment: that's the version I have, do you know any configuration that allows you to go outside?

Comment: Snaps are confined for security reasons.  They will not allow for that.  Remove the snap version and install the `.deb` version from https://linux.wps.com/

Comment: I solved the problem following your recommendation

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, specifically with WPS Office 2019 as installed via the snap/Ubuntu store. The way I fixed this was by opening the Ubuntu Software application, and changing the permissions specifically for WPS Office. Ensure that the last option "Read/write files on removable storage devices" is checked. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You can set it in the app store. Select the installed application, click permissions, allow the read drive.

Comment: I am vaguely aware that this is possible for some applications, but is it available specifically for WPS Office?